# Algebraic argument for why any $A_5$ in $S_6$ can be extended to an $S_5$ in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, platonic-solids

It is well known that $S_5$ is a subgroup of $S_6$ in a way that acts transitively on $6$ points, a surprising fact related to the outer automorphism of $S_6$. One can see this using the icosahedron: its rotational symmetry group is isomorphic to $A_5$, and acts transitively on the $6$ axes of the icosahedron that go through opposite vertices. One can show that this exotic $A_5$ in $S_6$ extends to an $S_5$ in $S_6$ (see [this](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/six.html) excellent page by John Baez), using some geometric observations.

Is there a purely algebraic way to see that any $A_5$ including into $S_6$ extends to an inclusion of $S_5$ in $S_6$, that avoids working directly with the icosahedron? If such an argument were slick enough, I might prefer it to the way Baez gives (not that I don't love the icosahedron!)

Comment: If an argument using the icosahedron can be found that's simpler than the one Baez gives, I'd be satisfied with that too.

Comment: Based on how this is worded, it sounds like you are trying to show that the _specific_ $A_5$ in $S_6$ given by the icosahedron axis action extends to an inclusion of $S_5$ into $S_6$ that is transitive. If so, then how can you avoid discussing the iscosahedron if that is so fundamental to this particular $A_5$? Or alternatively, would you want to start with some purely algebraic description of this particular $A_5$? Or alternatively, is the question whether _any_ transitive $A_5$ in $S_6$ can be extended to an inclusion of $S_5$ in $S_6$?

Comment: @alex.jordan You can avoid thinking about the icosahedron by proving that any transitive action of $A_5$ on six points extends to an action of $S_5$. That is what Ravi Fernando has done in their recent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we're given a transitive action of $A_5$ on a set $X$ of size 6.  Then the point stabilizers have order 10, which forces them to be the usual copies of $D_{10}$ in $A_5$; equivalently, these are the normalizers of the six Sylow 5-subgroups.  But this implies that $X$ is isomorphic as an $A_5$-set to the set $Syl_5(A_5)$ consisting of Sylow 5-subgroups of $A_5$ under conjugation.  Once you know this, it's clear that the $A_5$-action extends to an $S_5$-action:  $A_5$ and $S_5$ have the same Sylow 5-subgroups, so $S_5$ also acts on them by conjugation.

Comment: Oh, this is very nice! I just notice now that the Sylow-5 groups of A5 (viewed as icosahedron symmetries) are in bijection with the axes of the icosahedron, and geometrically one can see that the conjugation action on those subgroups is precisely the action on the axes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$A_5 \cong {\rm PSL}(2,5) < {\rm PGL}(2,5) \cong S_5$.

I suppose that doesn't show that the $A_5$ that is isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,5)$ is the same as (i.e. conjugate to in $S_5$) the $A_5$ that is the symmetry group of the icosahedron, but your could not really prove that without thinking about the icosahedron!

*Added*: You can avoid thinking about the icosahedron by proving directly that, up to conjugacy in $S_6$, $A_6$ has a unique transitive subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$. Here is a sketch proof.

$A_5$ is generated by $x,y$ with $x$, $y$, and $xy$ having order $2$, $3$ and $5$, respectively.

In the image in $A_6$, we can assume that $x=(1,2)(3,4)$. For $\langle x,y \rangle$ to be transitive, $y$ must consist of two $3$-cycles.

The essentially different possibilities for $y$ (by which I mean up to conjugation in $S_6$) are

(i) $y=(1,3,5)(2,4,6)$, $xy$ has order $3$;

(ii) $y=(1,3,5)(2,6,4)$, $xy$ has order $4$;

(iii) $y=(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$, $xy$ has order $5$.

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately I don't understand well those two isomorphisms you are using (though it's something I want to learn!)

Comment: It's also possible to use the fact that there is a unique conjugacy class of transitive subgroups of $S_6$ isomorphic to $A_5$ to prove directly that subgroups in that class must extend to $S_5$.